# How to supress the py.test one-character test result output?

Tags: python, pytest

When running tests with `py.test` you usually get the result of the test printed on the console as one character, i.e. a passed test is a dot '.', a failed test is 'F' and an error in the script is an 'E'.

I want to supress this output; no F's, E's etc. I tried to do the following in the `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=False)
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    return report.outcome, "", report.outcome.upper()
```

which, in fact, does supress the output!

However, on the downside, this magically increases the number reported at the end. So instead of 1 test I am getting 3(!) tests reported as passed:

```
=============================================================================== 3 passed in 0.06 seconds ================================================================================
```

But here is the complete test script:

```
class TestSuite(object):
    def test1(self):
        assert True
```

How to fix that? So the output only reports 1 (one) passed test, AND the test results (.FE) are supressed?

Comment: `pytest_report_teststatus` is called multiple times per test execution, at different stages. You need to properly handle this in the hook. Check out the answer in the linked question for a working example.

Comment: Yes thanks, that is a duplicate, and the given answer solved my problem.